# Request.IsAuthenticated is always false after logging into Microsoft AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, single-sign-on

I have an ASP.NET 4.5.1 MVC/WebAPI project. It authenticates against Microsoft using SSO. After successfully logging into Microsoft, I still have Request.IsAuthenticated on my HomeController. The url I have registered to web config file is http://localhost:58686/

Now, I have a sample MVC only application that successfully authenticates after login. I have double, triple checked the code and my mvc/Web Api project uses the same startup.cs, same web config structure and same registration to azure ad portal. But in this particular project, after logging into microsoft,  request.isauthentciated is always false. However, I get all the right claims from the context parameter on SecurityTokenValidated. Do you have any idea about why it is happening? Because I set up the project as MVC/WebAPI?
Home Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //var y = HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;


           if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
           {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["redirectUrl"] },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
```

Startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {

                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUrl,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUrl,
                    Scope = OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenIdProfile, 
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.IdToken,

                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters() { ValidateIssuer = false },


                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,

                        RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                        {
                            string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                            context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                            context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
                        SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                        {

                            var identity = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
```

Thank you and Kind Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Request.IsAuthenticated is always FALSE when you deal with `<authentication mode="Forms">` and always TRUE if you deal with `<authentication mode="Windows" />`. Please double check your web.config and remove this setting. After that the Request.IsAuthenticated is now defend on your AzureAD.