# ASP.net - Azure AD - Request.IsAuthenticated always false why? next

Tags: c#, azure, token

All my attempts to make working, as is,  the sample "**AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet**" have failed yet.
Redirection from **Azure AD** process seems occuring, a **token** is even present but "**Request.IsAuthenticated**" is always **false**.

I have checked and checked again that the required elements are correct, like the Client ID, the tenant , the URL to be redirected to . No errors of any sort are notified, I just get the homepage with the same sign in button. Access to the claims is never allowed.
Any idea?
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Access tokens option has been added but same result

Comment: Please don't make edits from another (unregistered) account to your own post. This frustrates the process in that others need to review that edit and then have to ascertain that it was made by the same person, but from a different account. Also having multiple accounts by the same owner interacting with one another may be seen as "cheating the system" and lead to bans. Therefore, please [edit] this question using the account that created it.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If you need further help, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

**Newest**

I have upload [my demo](https://github.com/Jason446620/AzureAD_WebAppOpenIDConnect), you just need to replace `ClientId`,`Tenant` and `redirectUri`.

Regarding the value of Tenant, you can use `TenantID` or `common`. The difference is that when you use TenantID, this app can only be used by users under this tenant. common can support other tenants.

**UPDATE**

When you want to deploy your app. You need to modify `web.config` file and `Redirect URIs` in portal like my screenshoots.

[image]

[image]

*Test Pic:*

[image]

[image]

[image]

**PRIVIOUS**

After reading your problem description, it is not clear why the problem occurred.

You can follow my steps to try again, I will show you step by step, your problem should be solved.

1. First add `App Registrations` in the portal.
2. In the portal, add or modify `Redirect URIs`, the default value is `https://localhost:44368/`, and enable `Access tokens` and `ID tokens`.

[image]

3. Modify the `ClientId` value of web.config in the project. ClientId is copied from the portal.

[image]

4. Set breakpoints in the HomeController.cs and Index.cshtml files, as in the screenshot below.

[image]

5. F5 run the project, see screenshots for the next steps, there will be a few notes.

Step1. Start with default page `Home/Index`.

[image]

Step2. Click Sign in with Microsoft, it will jump into breakpoint in `HomeController.cs` file. Because not sign in,so `Request.IsAuthenticated` is false.

[image]

Step3. When you input your account and pwd, it will redirect to `Home/Index`. Before that it will jump to breakpoint in `Index.cshtml` file. You can see the value of `Request.IsAuthenticated` after success login. It's true now.

[image]

Step4. Then you can see Index page.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for your inputs. So do you confirm the need to select also Access tokens then as right now only ID Token is selected, something I cannot do by myself, Azure AD settings are managed by a dedicated department in my company. By the way, the URI refers to localhost but I assume that this URI must be changed to the complete web URL address.

Comment: @ClaudeHornecker You can replace it. One is web.config file and another is in portal. It works，I will share you later.

Comment: Hi Jason. I have managed to get the option Access tokens implemented but that has not changed anything. still the sign in button  is displayed. the URI redirect is set with the complete web site address + the application root name.. I have a tenant ID so I have put this one in place of "common". It seems that I cannot reopen this post.

Comment: @ClaudeHornecker I have updated my answer, I think it useful to you.

Comment: Hi Jason, your change consisted in replacing the URI redirect to point to a webserver rather localhost/.... Something that was part of my configuration from the beginning. he tenant ID, you have not mentioned anything about is also different on my side as I put a single tenant ID in place of the value "common". But anyway that does not change anything to the issue as I still get back to the sign in page. Requested.isAuthenticated still giving false. Anyway Thanks for your effort to help me.

Comment: @ClaudeHornecker The value of Tenant you don't need to change. Can you just follow my step to do that?

Comment: Jason, I have tried both for the tenant, it does not work.

Comment: @ClaudeHornecker I also use tenantid  and test ,it works fine. I will update my answer and upload my demo to github, so you can use it.

Comment: @ClaudeHornecker, these answers might help you [remove forms authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882048/request-isauthenticated-is-always-false-after-logging-into-microsoft-ad) and [add cookie manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428993/getting-null-identity-while-authenticating-user-via-azure-ad-authentication)